# How to suppress advanced digitizing tool window

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, digitizing

I'm using QGis for years but suddenly I stuck with something that I'm sure it's an easy fix. Every time I start to create a new feature, the Advanced Digitizing tool window pops up. Do you know how to suppress it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When starting a new digitizing session, try dragging the Advanced Digitizing window and dropping it into one of the other toolbar panes or under layers window, you may have to double-click once you have it in the desired position.

If that fails, under "View" tab go to "Toolbars" and untick "Advanced Digitizing".

UPDATE: under "View" tab go to "Panels" and untick "Advanced Digitizing", hopefully this will work.

Comment: I tried that before but didn't work. Maybe I'll see if this is not there when I'll update to the next version. Meantime [I took a video to illustrate the problem.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2cr71i9e0346xp/advanced%20tool.mov?dl=0)

Comment: see update in answer ^